# batch for loop is not displaying needed components

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

Have the following and now is correct..  You cannot use the the FOR /f construct..  FOR %%G works correctly.

Edit - Not on my work computer, however I am seeing the same results..  So, just took D3F4ULT's code:

```
@echo off
echo Current Directory: %CD%
REM 22310611

for /f %%G in ( 'dir /b /a-d "C:\11\*"' ) do (
  echo f = %%~fG
  echo d = %%~dG
  echo p = %%~pG
  echo n = %%~nG
  echo x = %%~xG
  echo s = %%~sG
  echo a = %%~aG
  echo t = %%~tG
  echo z = %%~zG
  pause
)
```

And the result is:

```
Current Directory: C:\batch
f = C:\batch\!kix.zip
d = C:
p = \batch\
n = !kix
x = .zip
s = C:\batch\!kix.zip
a =
t =
z =
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Issues seen are:
C:\batch is the folder I am executing the script from
C:\11 is the target folder I am trying to get the information from..

Variable issues:
p is incorrect
a,t,z are not populated

Let's make the proposed change I suggested..

```
@echo off
echo Current Directory: %CD%
REM 22310611

REM - ORIGINAL: for /f %%G in ( 'dir /b /a-d "C:\11\*"' ) do (
for %%G in ( C:\11\* ) do (
  echo f = %%~fG
  echo d = %%~dG
  echo p = %%~pG
  echo n = %%~nG
  echo x = %%~xG
  echo s = %%~sG
  echo a = %%~aG
  echo t = %%~tG
  echo z = %%~zG
  pause
)
```

and the results are:

```
Current Directory: C:\batch

C:\batch>fllist.bat
Current Directory: C:\batch
f = C:\11\!kix.zip
d = C:
p = \11\
n = !kix
x = .zip
s = C:\11\!kix.zip
a = --a------
t = 07/31/2011 08:29 AM
z = 25732801
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Hope this helps with the understanding of what the issue is.

Comment: In what way does `echo %%~tG` "work fine" in the upper code, and not work down below? Show the exact code (in context) that is not working, describe what you expect, as well as what you are actually getting.

Comment: I have corrected the FOR structure and is displaying correctly now.

Comment: Show what the problem is.

Comment: Did update the post and now clearly shows where/how the error comes up.

Answer (score 0):

See if the code below works for you, if possible post the output of what happens there with you, using my code.

**Code:**

```
@echo off

REM 22310611

for /f %%G in ( 'dir /b /a-d "D:\logs\*"' ) do (
  echo f = %%~fG
  echo d = %%~dG
  echo p = %%~pG
  echo n = %%~nG
  echo x = %%~xG
  echo s = %%~sG
  echo a = %%~aG
  echo t = %%~tG
  echo z = %%~zG
  pause
)

pause
```

**Output**

```
f = D:\logs\1.jpg
d = D:
p = \logs\
n = 1
x = .jpg
s = D:\logs\1.jpg
a = ---------
t = 10/03/2014 16:55
z = 128928
```